# How to standardize JSON results of Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, active-model-serializers

I need to add extra tags to JSON results of Rails project.

**GET /menus**

```
{
  meta: {
    code: 200,
    message: ""
  }
  data: [
     // default rails response goes here
  ]
}
```

I don't want to do something like this in the controllers:

```
render json: { meta: { code: 200, message: ''}, data: @store.menus }
```

I looked in `active_model_serializers` gem, but didn't find any option that provides this type of customization.

Comment: Have you tried jbuilder? It makes building custom jquery structures easier in my experience https://github.com/rails/jbuilder

Comment: What do you mean extra tags? Comments? Comments aren't supported. If you are talking about adding new fields, and you're using JSON to serialize a hash, just add a new key/value to the hash before letting JSON have it.

Comment: This extra tags are useless, I just need to add them. Do not ask me why! So, i'm looking for a fancy way to handle this!

Comment: RE: The "Unclear what you're asking" close vote - This seems pretty clear to me. The OP wants to standardize the structure of the JSON responses in order to DRY up the controllers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a `JsonResponse` class to act as a view model to wrap the data you want to send back:

```
class JsonResponse
  attr_accessor :status, :message, :data

  STATUS_SUCCESS = 200;
  STATUS_CREATED = 201;
  STATUS_NOT_FOUND = 404;

  def self.success(data, message = nil)
    self.new(STATUS_SUCCESS, message || "OK", data)
  end

  def self.created(data, message = nil)
    self.new(STATUS_CREATED, message || "CREATED", data)
  end

  def self.not_found(data = nil, message = nil)
    self.new(STATUS_NOT_FOUND, message || "NOT FOUND", data)
  end

  def initialize(status = 200, message = "", data = nil)
    @status = status
    @message = message
    @data = data
  end

  def to_hash
    {
      meta: {
        code: status,
        message: message || ""
      },
      data: data.is_a?(Hash) ? data : data.to_hash
    }
  end
end
```

This gives you several ways of using this:

```
# One-liners
render json: JsonResponse.new(JsonResponse::STATUS_SUCCESS, nil, @store.menus).to_hash
render json: JsonResponse.success(@store.menus).to_hash
render json: JsonResponse.created(@store).to_hash
render json: JsonResponse.not_found.to_hash

# Multi-liners
response = JsonResponse.new JsonResponse::STATUS_SUCCESS, nil, @store.menus
response = JsonResponse.success @store.menus
response = JsonResponse.created @store
response = JsonResponse.not_found

# Render the JSON view
render json: response.to_hash
```